# Dúvida em lógica para tabela de comparativos entre planos - Está dando Timeout

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela no meu site, e hoje, ela é estática (não atualizável por CMSs). Ela tem mais linhas do que essa imagem, mas peguei só um pedaço para ilustrar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Hoje, no meu banco de dados, eu tenho esses 3 planos (ACO, ACO FIT e ACO Modular) cadastrados em uma tabela chamada "sistema_planos". Cada plano tem UM produto cadastrado em "sistema_produto" e interligados por uma tabela chamada "sistema_plano_produto". Dentro de cada produto, existem os módulos que, na imagem acima, são ilustrados alinhados na coluna da esquerda. Esses módulos estão cadastrados em uma tabela chamada "sistema_modulo" e interligados no produto através de uma tabela chamada "sistema_produto_modulo".

Preciso montar essa tabela da imagem consultando as informações no banco. Consegui, mas devido a alta quantidade de consultas, em 80% das vezes dá TIMEOUT.

Então, acho que há algo errado na lógica que construí. Gostaria de dicas de como proceder!

```
$divTabela = "";
$listaHead01 = "";
$listaHead02 = "";
$listaModulo = "";
$listaFoot = "";

/ * Traz os planos pra montar a tabela
$objPlano = new Plano();
$objPlano->plaAtivo = "S";
$objPlano->plaExcluido = "N";
$resultadoPlano = $objPlano->load(false, "plaValor DESC");

if(!empty($resultadoPlano)){

    // * Inicia os objetos
    $objPlanoProduto = new PlanoProduto();
    $objProdutoModulo = new ProdutoModulo();

    $objModulo = new Modulo();
    $objModulo->modAtivo = "S";
    $objModulo->modExcluido = "N";

    $arrayProdutoId = array();

    // * Loop de planos
    foreach($resultadoPlano as $plano){

        $valorPlano = (!empty($plano['plaValor'])) ? "A partir de<br><span>R$".number_format($plano['plaValor'],2,",",".")."</span> mensais<br><small>+ Taxa de ativação da licença e tempo mínimo de contrato: 12 meses</small>" : "Consulte";

        // * Headings
        $listaHead01 .= "<th width=\"20%\">".$plano['plaTitulo']."</th>";
        $listaHead02 .= "<th>".$valorPlano."</th>";

        // * Footers
        $listaFoot .= "<td><a class=\"btn-arq\" href=\"/produto/".$plano['plaAlias']."\">Mais detalhes</a></td>";

        // * Precisamos saber agora qual ícone irá em cada TD
        // * Para isso, traremos primeiro o produto do plano $i
        // * Com o produto definido, podemos saber quais módulos cada produto tem disponível
        $objPlanoProduto->plaId = $plano['plaId'];
        $resultadoPlanoProduto = $objPlanoProduto->load();

        if(!empty($resultadoPlanoProduto)){
            $arrayProdutoId[] = $resultadoPlanoProduto[0]['proId'];
        }

    }

    // * Traz a lista de módulos
    $resultadoModulo = $objModulo->load();

    if(!empty($resultadoModulo)){

        foreach($resultadoModulo as $modulo){

            // * Inicia as variáveis
            $tdPlano = "";

            // * Tbody
            // * Pra cada plano, cria uma TD
            for($i = 0; $i < count($resultadoPlano); $i++){

                $iconeCheck = "";

                // * Agora, trazemos os módulos do produto
                $objProdutoModulo->proId = $arrayProdutoId[$i];
                $objProdutoModulo->modId = $modulo['modId'];
                $resultadoProdutoModulo = $objProdutoModulo->load(true);

                if(!empty($resultadoProdutoModulo)){

                    // * Verifica se o produto é modular
                    if($resultadoPlano[$i]['plaValor'] > 0){
                        $iconeCheck = "<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i>";
                    }
                    else{
                        $iconeCheck = "<i data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Item opcional. Consulte adição.\" class=\"fa fa-question\"></i>";
                    }
                }

                // * Monta no template
                $tdPlano .= "<td>".$iconeCheck."</td>";

            }

            $listaModulo .= "
            <tr>
                <td>".$modulo['modTitulo']."</td>
                ".$tdPlano."
            </tr>";
        }

    }

    $divTabela = "
    <table class=\"tabelaPreco table table-bordered table-striped\">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width=\"20%\" style=\"background:#f3f3f3\"></th>
                ".$listaHead01."
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style=\"background:#f3f3f3\"></th>
                ".$listaHead02."
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ".$listaModulo."
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                ".$listaFoot."
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>";
}
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar logs no meio do código para saber o ponto que mais leva tempo?

Comment: @Pagotti a consulta que está dentro do for: $resultadoProdutoModulo = $objProdutoModulo->load(true); Essa demora mais. Mas demora pela quantidade de vezes que é realizada, e não pela sua construção em si.

Comment: Isso é ruim mesmo porque são dois loops aninhados. Nesse caso não vejo como otimizar o código pq o tempo de banco é bem maior. Acho que o melhor é ver se consegue otimizar a consulta no banco para fazer uma vez só ou pelo menos tirar de dentro do último loop.